# Cookie Script - Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a EU cookie script, but can't seem to fix it. The error is as follows:

> - Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

I'm running the script on WordPress. jQuery is already present before this script is loaded.

The script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    e.CookiesMessage = function(o) { // this line creates the error
        function n(o) {
            var i = "";
            1 == o.closeEnable && (i += '<a href="#" id="optr-cookies-close" style="background-color:' + o.closeBgColor + ';"><svg version="1.1" id="optr-cookies-close-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="248.5 248.5 15 15" enable-background="new 248.5 248.5 15 15" xml:space="preserve" ><polygon id="x-mark-icon" points="263.5,260.876 258.621,255.999 263.499,251.121 260.876,248.5 256,253.377 251.122,248.5 248.5,251.121 253.378,255.999 248.5,260.878 251.121,263.5 256,258.62 260.879,263.499" style="fill:' + o.closeColor + ';"/></svg></a>');
            var n = "";
            1 == o.acceptEnable && (n += '<a href="#" id="optr-cookies-ok">' + o.acceptText + "</a>"), 1 == o.infoEnable && (n += '<a href="' + o.infoUrl + '" id="optr-cookies-info">' + o.infoText + "</a>");
            var c = '<div id="optr-cookies"><p>' + o.messageText + n + "</p>" + i + "</div>";
            e("body").prepend(c), e("#optr-cookies").hide().slideDown(), e("#optr-cookies").css({
                "background-color": o.messageBg,
                color: o.messageColor
            }), e("#optr-cookies p a").css({
                color: o.messageLinkColor
            })
        }

        function c(e) {
            return e.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")
        }

        function s(e) {
            var o = !1;
            if (document.cookie) {
                var n = document.cookie.split(";");
                for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
                    var s = n[i].split("=");
                    c(s[0]) == e && (o = s[1])
                }
            }
            return o
        }

        function a(e, o, i, n) {
            var c = new Date;
            c.setTime(c.getTime() + 24 * i * 60 * 60 * 1e3);
            var s = "expires=" + c.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = e + "=" + o + "; " + s + "; path=" + n + ";"
        }
        var l = {
            messageText: "We use technical and analytics cookies to ensure that we give you the best experience on our website.",
            messageBg: "#151515",
            messageColor: "#FFFFFF",
            messageLinkColor: "#F0FFAA",
            closeEnable: !0,
            closeColor: "#444444",
            closeBgColor: "#000000",
            acceptEnable: !0,
            acceptText: "Accept & Close",
            infoEnable: !0,
            infoText: "More Info",
            infoUrl: "#",
            cookieExpire: 180
        };
        o = e.extend(l, o);
        var t = location.host,
            r = "Cookies policy accepted",
            d = "/",
            g = s(t);
        g || n(o), e("#optr-cookies-ok").on("click", function(i) {
            i.preventDefault(), a(t, r, o.cookieExpire, d), e("#optr-cookies").slideToggle()
        }), e("#optr-cookies-close").on("click", function(o) {
            o.preventDefault(), e("#optr-cookies").slideToggle()
        })
    }
});
```

I really hope someone can help me out with this. Thank you!

I took the script from [this website](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Responsive-EU-Cookie-Law-Notice-Plugin-For-jQuery-Cookies-Message.html).

---

Edit: this error came up after fixing the above.

> Uncaught TypeError: $.CookiesMessage is not a function

Leads to this line:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.CookiesMessage({ // this one
        messageText: "We use technical and analytics cookies to ensure that we give you the best experience on our website.",
        messageBg: "#151515",
        messageColor: "#FFFFFF",
        messageLinkColor: "#F0FFAA",
        closeEnable: true,
        closeColor: "#444444",
        closeBgColor: "#000000",
        acceptEnable: true,
        acceptText: "Accept & Close",
        infoEnable: true,
        infoText: "More Info",
        infoUrl: "#",
        cookieExpire: 180
    });
});
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="no-js">
    <head>  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpresstest/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpresstest/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpresstest/wp-content/plugins/cookiez*emphasized text*/js/cookies.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>

<style type="text/css">#optr-cookies { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: 200; width: 100%; padding: 15px 0; text-align: center; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.1; background-color: #151515; color: #FFF; box-shadow: 0 -3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15) } #optr-cookies p { margin: 0; padding: 0 50px } #optr-cookies-info, #optr-cookies-ok { display: inline-block; color: #F0FFAA; font-weight: 700; text-decoration: underline; margin-left: 10px; cursor: pointer } #optr-cookies-close { height: 16px; width: 16px; padding: 8px; position: absolute; right: 7px; top: 50%; margin-top: -16px; -moz-border-radius: 16px; -webkit-border-radius: 16px; border-radius: 16px; background-color: #000 } @media (max-width: 768px) { #optr-cookies p { padding: 15px 15px 0 } #optr-cookies-info, #optr-cookies-ok { display: block; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px 5px; margin-top: 10px; background-color: #444; -moz-border-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; border-radius: 2px } #optr-cookies-close { left: 50%; margin-left: -16px; top: 0 } }</style><script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.CookieMessage = function(o) {};
});</script>
    </head>
    <body id="document" class="home blog logged-in one-column">
        <!-- website -->

    </body><!-- #document -->
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you get `e` variable in this line?

Comment: Where did you get this code from? There is different at website you provided.

Comment: @Maxx This is the script: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-EU-Cookie-Law-Notice-Plugin-For-jQuery-Cookies-Message/dist/cookies-message.min.js - I ran it through JSBeautifier.org

Comment: I see, but what your script do? Did you just copypaste part of that file to your script? Or where you get this code?

Comment: @Maxx Just copy and paste and then made it wordpress compatible

Comment: About `Uncaught TypeError: $.CookiesMessage is not a function`. Remove `$` from `function($)`

Answer (score 1):

I think i understood what you did.

replace whole your js code with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.CookiesMessage({});
});
```

don't forget about

```
<link href="dist/cookies-message.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="dist/cookies-message.min.js"></script>
```

**after** jQuery loading

Comment: got it loaded after jquery, but I need the script in my `<head>` so I can adjust the settings

Comment: You can place it in head, just after jQuery and plugin.

Comment: Okay, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` on line 60, line 60 is this line: `messageBg: "#151515",`

Comment: Try it with empty object as in my answer, just copypaste whole my code. Did it work?

Comment: I've changed your code with the code Tim Vermaelen provided and no error pops up, but how can I add the settings code to it though?

Comment: so I can't add settings? Without the settings my cookie alert won't pop up :(

Comment: Your cookie don't popup because his code is not for your case. Documentation on site clearly says `$.CookiesMessage(OPTIONS);`. Add code of your full page or i give up with this.

Comment: added to question.

Comment: Well, you said you used my code.. Code that you provided do nothing. Just replace it with `$(document).ready(function(){
    $.CookiesMessage({});
}` isn't it hard for you?

Comment: Yes but I like you can see in my example, the website is powered by Wordpress, and WordPress needs to run jQuery in noConflict, so that's why I cannot add your code.

Comment: ok, `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery.CookiesMessage({}); }`

Comment: Added the code but got missing list arguement or something, so I changed `}` to `});` but then I got `(index):57 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.CookiesMessage is not a function`, I'm about to give up on this code like I did with the 4 previous ones

Comment: That was my mistake. You fixed it right. Last chance, check your url http://localhost/wordpresstest/wp-content/plugins/cookiez*emphasized text*/js/cookies.js?ver=1.0.0 just open it in your browser. I think something wrong with `*emphasized text*`

Answer (score 0):

It's `e.CookiesMessage` that is the problem. Since e is `undefined` you're not going to be able to bind another Object into it.

Try this:

```
var e = e || {};
e.CookiesMessage = function(o) { // this line creates the error
```

This will most likely solve your problem.

Now as we are all a bit inspectors, `e` is most likely part of an **E**vent handler and therefor we can assume you copy/pasted this code from somewhere else. To make sense of this try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.CookieMessage = function(o) {
        // and the rest of the code
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. A different error come up, `TypeError: $.CookiesMessage is not a function` which is located inside the head tag, I will update my question